# Redirect a single dynamic URL with Apache .htaccess to temporary page

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, dynamic, temporary

Here is what I need to redirect to a temporary HTML page:

```
http://www.domain1.com/?Itemid=230
```

should get redirected to:

```
http://www.domain2.com/temoporary-solution.html
```

Here is what I came up with, just not sure if it will cause any issues between the rest of the .htaccess rules (this is the first rule):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^Itemid=230$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://domain2.com/temoporary-solution.html [R=302,NE,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule should work fine. Just append `?` at the end of target URI to strip off existing query string:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Itemid=230$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://domain2.com/temoporary-solution.html? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: One last question, this rule does not work without www - what would be the correct format to work with both w/ and w/o 'www'? Thank you!

Comment: That's the reason why I made `www` option by using `(www\.)?` Are you sure `www.domain1.com` is going at same place as `domain.com`?

Comment: It works perfect, I was focusing on your comment and missed that you have fixed the www part as well. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Those rules are fine. The conditions are pretty strict so as long as it's the first rule, it won't break anything else.